# Is there any naturally occurring light wave with a constant frequency that has a terminable decimal.

Tags: time, frequency, wavelength

I was wanting to think of a natural unit of time, if one exists, that is known exactly. I started thinking about it with the Voyager plaque and the 21 cm Hydrogen line (HL). When I looked into the HL, however, there didn't seem to be exact representations. For example, Wikipedia gives 1420.405751786 MHz, but when I plug this into Wolfram Alpha, it tells me this number is "approximately equal to..." Furthermore, this stackexchange answer on the Voyager Golden Record gives the number 1420.40575177 MHz, which is less precise and slightly off from wikipedia, but nonetheless gets the same response from Wolfram Alpha: that it's an approximate. So, is there any naturally occurring light that is always emitted at an exact frequency, where the frequency is exactly known, and is a terminable decimal? If so, what is it? Furthermore, I don't have much have faith in my math skills. It took me four times to find that 1420.40575177 MHz has a period of 704ns and that was only because I knew the answer so could try again. So, could you tell me EXACTLY the period, regardless of how many decimals, so long as it is terminable. Thank you.

Comment: The hydrogen line is exactly 1 in units of the hydrogen line frequency. You are getting caught up in numerology, instead of focusing on physics.

Comment: What is wrong with a unit of time based on the [Planck time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time)?  Just like the meter is based on a small percentage of the earth's circumference, a standard planck time unit could just be planck x 10^44 or roughly 5.39 seconds.

Comment: What makes you think it *is* terminable (in decimal)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is formally defined as the duration of 9,192,631,770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the Cesium 133 atom.

So you have the right approach, but are a few decades late to the race

Comment: Better late than never? lol